# Libreoffice Calc add dupliacte entries

Tags: libreoffice, automation, functions

I have a generated csv of items sold with quantity sold, on transaction per line.
There are many transactions of the same items and I would like to automate adding the numbers of the same items.
I have been doing it manually and it takes a long time. I am not sure where to look to implement this. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

I have attached a picture of before and after.

Thank you

[before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytDOB.png)

Comment: See this: https://superuser.com/questions/1241470/libreoffice-count-distinct-values-from-column

Comment: Thank you very much Jim! That is perfect!